# How to check current time lies between two given time Moment

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm trying to check whether a time lies between two times or not using a moment. I have tried like this

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

current_day_time.current_time = 2021-06-18T08:03Z
batch_info.batch_start_time = 2021-06-17T03:30:29.351Z,
batch_info.batch_end_time = 2021-06-17T12:30:32.191Z


 const current_time = moment(current_day_time.current_time);
 const start = moment(batch_info.batch_start_time);
 const end = moment(batch_info.batch_end_time);


 
current = Fri Jun 18 2021 13:32:00 GMT+0530
start = Thu Jun 17 2021 09:00:29 GMT+0530
end = Thu Jun 17 2021 18:00:32 GMT+0530

 console.log(moment(current_time).isBetween(start, end)); // false
```

As we can clearly see 13 lies between 9-18 still I'm getting false. How can I compare only time?

Comment: It is `Jun 18` which doesn't fall between two dates of `Jun 17`.

Comment: I just want to compare time @Mr_Green.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with the javascript method as well. Which will return your date time in seconds and then you can compare those, as they will be in the form of a number. For example, see the image:

[image: Results]

> new Date(`your_date`).getTime()

```js
import * as moment from 'moment';

current_day_time.current_time = 2021 - 06 - 18 T08: 03 Z
batch_info.batch_start_time = 2021 - 06 - 17 T03: 30: 29.351 Z,
  batch_info.batch_end_time = 2021 - 06 - 17 T12: 30: 32.191 Z


const current_time = moment(current_day_time.current_time);
const start = moment(batch_info.batch_start_time);
const end = moment(batch_info.batch_end_time);

current = Fri Jun 18 2021 13: 32: 00 GMT + 0530
start = Thu Jun 17 2021 09: 00: 29 GMT + 0530
end = Thu Jun 17 2021 18: 00: 32 GMT + 0530


let current_d = new Date("Fri Jun 18 2021 13:32:00 GMT+0530").getTime()
let start_d = new Date("Thu Jun 17 2021 09:00:29 GMT+0530").getTime()
let end_d = new Date("Thu Jun 17 2021 18:00:32 GMT+0530").getTime()

if (current_d > start_d && current_d < end_d) {
  console.log('In')
}

//console.log(moment(current_time).isBetween(start, end)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const format = 'hh:mm:ss'

// const time = moment() gives you current time. no format required.
const time = moment('09:34:00',format);
const beforeTime = moment('08:34:00', format);
const afterTime = moment('10:34:00', format);

if (time.isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime)) {
  console.log('is between')
} else {
  console.log('is not between')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you compare complete dates, in that case a time from 2021-06-18 will never fall between 2 dates on 2021-06-17. Without using `moment.js` maybe the next snippet is an idea?

```js
let startTime = new Date('2021-06-17T03:30:29.351Z');
let endTime = new Date('2021-06-17T12:30:32.191Z');
let currentTime = new Date('2021-06-18T08:03Z');

console.log(timeWithin(currentTime, startTime, endTime));

const compareTimes = TimeComparerFactory()
console.log(compareTimes(currentTime, startTime, endTime));

// time comparison for complete dates
function timeWithin(time, start, end) {
  return time > start && time < end;
}

// time comparison for time only
// where the time of a date is converted to a number
// (disregarding milliseconds)
function TimeComparerFactory() {
  const pad = v => `${v}`.padStart(2, `0`);
  const t2Nr = date => {
    const dStr = date.toISOString();
    return +( dStr.split("T")[1].split(/[:+-.]/, 3).map(pad).join("") );
  };
  
  return (time, start, end) => {
    time = t2Nr(time);
    return time > t2Nr(start) && time < t2Nr(end);
  }
}
```